# Can I turn off push notifications for The Simpsons: Tapped Out?

Tags: android, simpsons-tapped-out

While I really love playing The Simpsons: Tapped Out, I find the push notifications annoying, especially the soundbites that go along with them. I want to be able to have the sound up on my phone so that I can hear if someone calls me or the like, but I hate those notifications.

I can't seem to find a way to turn them off, though. Am I just missing a setting, or is there really no way to turn off the push notifications for this game?

Comment: Are you on Android or Apple?

Comment: oh, this is on Android :)

Comment: http://tstotopix.me/2014/01/06/homer-no-yell-please/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to do it in game. Pull up the build menu and click on the "I" to bring up settings

[image]

Then simply turn push notifications to off

[image]

Answer (score 8):

On Android 4.1 and higher you can disable notifications for each app separately. Just go to Settings -> Apps and then select the correct app. There is a "Show notifications" checkbox in the top left, unchecking this will prevent the app from pushing notifications.

Here is a screenshot of that screen, the "Show notifications" checkbox is right under the Force Stop button:

[image]

Comment: Well, yes, I suppose that's simpler. >.>

Comment: I am running 4.2.1 and I don't see this option....

Comment: @AshleyNunn I've added a screenshot where the option should be

Comment: Even easier in 4.1+ is to press and hold on the notification, click on 'App Info', and uncheck from there... Just a shortcut for other apps, or if you don't know which app is causing the notification.

Answer (score 4):

There likely isn't an option in the game itself, but you can probably disable them from your device.

On Android 4.1 and newer, you can open *Settings*, then *Apps*, then *Tapped Out*, and then uncheck the "Show notifications" option. If your Android version is older than that, you could use [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) to stop apps from running in the background, which should stop Push Notifications, although it may have side effects if the game requires running in the background.

For iOS, you can see [this question on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28883/how-can-i-turn-off-push-notifications-for-individual-apps-in-ios-5), but basically you go to the app's settings, then *Notifications*, and then turn them off.

Answer (score 1):

There actually IS a setting *in the game* to supposedly disable push notifications.  That doesn't seem to work at all and hasn't for a while -- though way back, it did work.  Having it turned off, I still get notifications that someone has visited my town.  The remedy for this is the setting mentioned above in Android itself to disable notifications for the app.  This is 100% effective.  You should not have to be using that to disable the notifications, because I would expect that the in-app notification setting should be working properly.  It isn't, though.